# Capturing video automatically and saved in phone in cordova android

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins

I have implemented video capturing facility in cordova using this plugin(https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/VideoCapturePlus-PhoneGap-Plugin). But I need capture the video automatically and save to memory without any user actions,Also i want to get the path of saved Video.Is it possible with this plugin??

```
//this only prompt to turn on camera automatically 
    window.plugins.videocaptureplus.captureVideo(captureSuccess, captureError, {limit:1, duration:10});
```

Also i want to get the path of saved Video

Comment: Camera only opens only on video mode and the rest of the things has to be done manually by the user

Comment: AFAIK it's not possible. Even if it's possible, Market policies will stop it. Imagine any app suddenly starts, capture something and upload it online. Horrible result :)

Comment: In cm security antivirus app lock, there is feature that automatically takes the photo of someone who entered the wrong password twice.So this wlll also possible in video??

Answer (score 0):

I used the [Cordova LibraryHelper plugin](https://github.com/coryjthompson/cordova-library-helper). It has a method that will save to the native camera roll/app, just pass it the mediafile path after you grab it with VideoCapturePlus and pass the name of the album you want the files to save it.

It supports Android & iOS although I've only used it for iOS.